# referencing rpart terminal nodes in r

Tags: r, rpart

I am new to R (and rpart).  I have vehicle model data (~400 models).  I am using rpart to group these into a smaller number (say 5-10 groups) that have similar vehicle repair costs.  I have successfully run rpart and have these groupings.

```
fit <- rpart(repairs ~ model, data=data, method='anova', control=rpart.control(minsplit=2,minbucket=1,cp=.0005))
```

Assume each terminal node has roughly 40-80 models in it.  Is there an way for me to create a formula that refers to the values in the terminal node.  Assuming data$model contains all of the model names (and is the independent variable I am trying to do something like:

```
data$modelgroup <- data$model
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup %in% terminal node 1] <- 'Group1'
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup %in% terminal node 2] <- 'Group2'
and so on for the rest of the groups
```

Also, if there were a way to do this without having to have a line of code for each group, that would be good.

I know I can print the tree and manually copy the text from the terminal nodes and accomplish it that way, but that is very inefficient.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Per the request below, I added a reproducible example below.

```
data <- read.csv("rpart_example.csv")
data

data[,1:2]

   Model Amount
1      a      1
2      a      1
3      a      1
4      b      1
5      b      1
6      b      1
7      c      2
8      c      2
9      c      2
10     d      2
11     d      2
12     d      2
13     e      3
14     e      3
15     e      3
16     f      4
17     f      4
18     f      4

fit <- rpart(Amount ~ Model, data=data, method='anova', 
          control=rpart.control(minsplit=2,minbucket=1,cp=.0005))
print(fit)

n= 18 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
* denotes terminal node

1) root 18 20.5 2.166667  
2) Model=a,b,c,d 12  3.0 1.500000  
4) Model=a,b 6  0.0 1.000000 *
  5) Model=c,d 6  0.0 2.000000 *
  3) Model=e,f 6  1.5 3.500000  
6) Model=e 3  0.0 3.000000 *
  7) Model=f 3  0.0 4.000000 *

# create a variable modelgroup that groups models per terminal nodes from rpart     

# I can do this manually as below
# is there a way for me to automate this assignment?

data$modelgroup <- as.character(data$Model)

# per rpart output, a&b are grouped into one terminal node
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup %in% c('a','b')] <- 'Group1'    

# per rpart output, c&d are grouped into the second terminal node
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup %in% c('c','d')] <- 'Group2'

# per rpart, e is the third terminal node
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup == 'e'] <- 'Group3'

# per rpart, f is the fourth terminal node
data$modelgroup[data$modelgroup == 'f'] <- 'Group4'
```

Comment: If would be easier to help you if your provide a minimal [reproducible example]. Include some sample data and specify the desired output for that input.

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide a reproducible example, but as an illustration, say after running rpart and print(fit), one of the terminal nodes contained FordTaurus, ChevyMalibu...and 40+ more model names.  Say I want to call all of the models listed in this terminal node "Group 1". I essentially want code to say if the model name is in this list, call it "Group 1" and do that for each of the terminal nodes.

Comment: It's not easy to offer hypothetical solutions. Perhaps you could adapt the example from the `rpart` help page to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I hadn't been able to get back to this until now.  Per your request, I added a reproducible example. I added it at the bottom of my original post.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `rpart` objects the information you are looking for is essentially readily stored in the `$where` element. It gives you the node number to which each observation is assigned:

```
table(fit$where, data$modelgroup)
##     Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
##   3      6      0      0      0
##   4      0      6      0      0
##   6      0      0      3      0
##   7      0      0      0      3
```

Of course you could also switch the node IDs (3, 4, 6, 7) to a factor or character variable, e.g., `factor(fit$where, levels = c(3, 4, 6, 7), labels = paste0("Group", 1:4))` or something along those line.

If you want to do this on new data with a simple and unified interface, you can convert your `rpart` object to a `party` object in package `partykit`:

```
library("partykit")
fit2 <- as.party(fit)
```

The unified methods for `print(fit2)` and `plot(fit2)` are available as well as `predict(fit2, ...)` with different types:

```
table(predict(fit2, newdata = data, type = "node"), data$modelgroup)
##     Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
##   3      6      0      0      0
##   4      0      6      0      0
##   6      0      0      3      0
##   7      0      0      0      3
```

This returns the same result as above but could easily be applied to other `newdata` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I appreciate it!  I tried using the suggested code (table(fit$where, data$modelgroup)), but received an error message. I am also confused as to what this is intended to do.  In my example above, how do I use this to assign 'Group 1' to the new variable data$modelgroup for models a & b (since they are together in the first terminal node)?

Comment: The table is supposed to show that the grouping from `fit$where` and the manually constructed `modelgroup` coincide, i.e., provide the same group information. I cannot comment on the error without a self-contained example reproducing the error message. The example I used is the simple 18 observation dataset you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I got it to work. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I adapted your response and used the following code. Thanks again! data$modelgroup <- factor(fit$where,levels = levels(factor(fit$where)),
+                 labels=paste0("Group",1:nlevels(factor(fit$where))))